# How should I go about running OpenGL on a linux machine with no GPU?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, headless

I've been trying to figure out how to run softwares that require OpenGL (specifically, they use SDL) to run. I had some success with setting up a VNC server as a display but that was inconsistent at best, and would not actually work long term for what I'm trying to do. Everything that I tried involving a VNC server as a display came back with "GLX is not supported" types of errors on most software that I tried to run that tried to create a display.

My goal isn't to get a display working, I just need the program to run, preferably without rendering, as what it's doing CPU-wise is what's important to me. Is there a no-op OpenGL implementation for Linux, or more specifically Ubuntu, that doesn't require a display?

How should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: opengl has a no-video option described in the documentation

Comment: Can you link me to where that might be?